# iOS Hack - “Please Reboot Your Mobile”

Tags: iphone, ios, hacking

I just started seeing this screen appear on my phone. It's an iPhone 6 with iOS 9.1 - factory unlocked - never jailbroken - never done anything even remotely unusual with it. It's obviously a hack of sorts. I didn't press "accept" or "decline" just took a screenshot. There is no "app" visible on the home screen, and nothing running in the background (that I can see).

Can't find anything online that relates as to what this could be, or where it could come from. Very curious to know.

Notes:

- The back button just takes you to the home screen.
- I wiped the phone to factory settings, and the screen reappeared while I was still on the "hello/welcome" page.
- This is not a support question. I 'm curious to know if anybody has heard of this exploit.

[image]

Comment: This looks like an App displaying a message of "Please reboot your mobile". Strange that if you tap "< Back" it takes you to the home screen. What app is running in the task switcher? And which version of iOS are you running?

Comment: Found an old post on discussions.apple.com from 2011: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3336469?tstart=0 . Could this be a hardware issue?

Comment: There is no app running in the task switcher. As mentioned in my question this happened even after erasing the phone and I was in the initial configuration screen. I'm on iOS 9.1 on iPhone 6

Comment: If the message is being generated by "Springboard" then there could be an internal hardware error in your iPhone. I would contact Apple support and start going through their process (I think you can run a hardware check at some point?)

Comment: Just spoke with Apple Support. This is not an official Apple screen of any kind. They confirmed it is a hack.

Comment: Interesting. Did they say how it survived a fresh iOS installation?

Comment: It appears that the hack had found it's way to the SIM card, that's how it survived the fresh installation. I've replaced the SIM and am having the suspect one examined. It's a successful exploit though, because even though I didn't click "accept" a few hours later I got a notification that somebody was attempting to login to my iCloud account from a new device in a different country.

Comment: Wow. So this isn't an iOS hack but a GSM SIM hack. I knew that SIMs have been targeted in the past but I'd hoped that the network operators had replaced all the old cards and upgraded their systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module . Just out of interest - what is your country and network operator?